# High resistance (100Mohm) control using constant voltage or current source

Tags: resistance

I want to control resistance (100Mohm) programmatically. I found on this site that photoFET can solve this issue by sourcing constant current.  From my understanding  FET can give resistance control over orders of 1 to 2Mohm. Apart  from this I want to drop 5000V dc(5kv) across this resistance. So what should I use? i.e Range of variation for this resistor needs to be from few 100 Megaohm to few kiloohms. A small amount of current 50 micro amperes flows in the circuit.

Comment: Sounds hard.  I assume a bunch of HV relays (to switch resistors) is too expensive.

Comment: What is the min and max the resistance needs to be?  Saying it needs to be 100 MOhm means you can use a fixed 100 MOhm resistor since it doesn't need to change.

Comment: 100 Mohm to few kilo ohm range

Comment: 5kV across 10k is 2500 watts.  Have fun!

Comment: It seems to me to that this could possibly work by using vacuum tubes, however, this is just an speculation since I'm not very well-versed in vacuum tubes. Perhaps someone with more knowledgeable could enlightened us.

Comment: Where was the answer indicating about capacitive switching?  I was trying to understand it.

Comment: I am not able to find your answer here now about capacitive switching@Scott Seidman